# R, Flag if entry is out of possible range

Tags: r, range

I have a number of surveys that were completed on paper, then entered into Excel spreadsheets a by hand.

I want to make a new column that **specifies when there is a number that was entered outside the possible range (1-4)**

This is what I have but I am sure there is a better way to do this.

```
function(x) 
{for (v in 1:length(x)) assign(names(x)[v], x[[v]])
 if(var1 <= 1 & var1 >= 4 &
    var2 <= 1 & var2 >= 4 & 
    var3 <= 1 & var3 >= 4 &
    var4 <= 1 & var4 >= 4 &
    var5 <= 1 & var5 >= 4 & 
        ...       
    var28 <= 1 & var5 >= 28) {within_value <- "TRUE"}
 else { within_value <- "FALSE"}
}
```

I want something like the "within_range" column here:

```
Name       var1    var2    var3  ...  var27  var28   within_range
Sub100      1       5       4            3     8     FALSE
Sub101      2       4       3            5     1     TRUE
Sub102      5       2       1            1     2     TRUE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `data.table::between()`

```
library(data.table)
df1$within_range <- sapply(1:nrow(df1), function(x) 
  all(between(df1[x, -1], 1, 6)))  # e.g. between 1 and 6
```

Or - if you prefer a straight base solution you could do

```
df1$within_range <- sapply(1:nrow(df1), function(x) { 
  tr <- df1[x, -1]
  all(tr >= 1 & tr <= 6)
})
```

**Result**

```
> df1
    Name var1 var2 var3 var27 var28 within_range
1 Sub100    1    5    4     3     8        FALSE
2 Sub101    2    4    3     5     1         TRUE
3 Sub102    5    2    1     1     2         TRUE
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Sub100", "Sub101", 
"Sub102"), class = "factor"), var1 = c(1L, 2L, 5L), var2 = c(5L, 
4L, 2L), var3 = c(4L, 3L, 1L), var27 = c(3L, 5L, 1L), var28 = c(8L, 
1L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @jay.sfI went with the straight base solution as it was easier for me to follow, thank you!